# How to create an Object from an Bean Definition in Spring 4?

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I have a method with return type 'AbstractBeanDefinition', this method is supposed to set all the necessary properties and return it.

```
    public AbstractBeanDefinition constructJMSMessage() {

    BeanDefinitionBuilder theMessagingService =  BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(MessagingService.class);
    theMessagingService.addPropertyValue(..);
    theMessagingService.addPropertyValue(..);
    theMessagingService.addPropertyValue(..);

    return theMessagingService.getBeanDefinition()

}
```

In the caller place, i want to create a object based on the bean defintion returned by this method. How can i do that ?

```
   public void ConstructIt()
  {
     MessagingService obj = constructJMSMessage();
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to register `BeanDefinition` with the `BeanDefinitionRegistry` (with is usually a `DefaultListableBeanFactory` instance) first and then use it as a regular bean.

```
FileSystemXmlApplicationContext c = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext();
c.refresh();

BeanDefinitionRegistry bdr = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) c.getBeanFactory();
BeanDefinitionBuilder bdb = BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(String.class)
        .addConstructorArgValue("test");
BeanDefinition bd = bdb.getBeanDefinition();
bdr.registerBeanDefinition("testBean", bd);

String tb = c.getBean("testBean", String.class);
```